# In Python, how do you do substitutions when the template file contains a "$"?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, templates, substitution

I'm using Python 3.7 and Django.  I want to get a string from a template in Python and make the apporpriate substitutions like so ...

```
src = Template(filein.read())
# document data
relative_path = article.path.replace(settings.REDDIT_URL_PREFIX, "")
d = {'relative_path': relative_path, 'comment': comment}
# do the substitution
result = src.substitute(d)
```

However, there is one problem.  My template contains this

```
    ["xpath=//a[@onclick='$(this).parent().submit()']", "xpath:attributes"],
```

The dollar sign is usually used for substitution, and so maybe for this reason, my above code is dying with the error ...

```
ValueError: Invalid placeholder in string: line 248, col 31
```

Does anyone know how I modify the above template line so that the substitution mechanism ignores the dollar sign on that line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three options:

1) Follow the escaping rules
https://www.simplifiedpython.net/python-template-class/

- “$$“ is an escape ; it is replaced with a single “$“.
- “$identifier“ names a substitution placeholder matching a mapping key
  of “identifier”. By default, “identifier” must spell a Python
  identifier. The first non-identifier character after the “$”
  character terminates this placeholder specification.
- “${identifier}“ is equivalent to “$identifier“. It is required when
  valid identifier characters follow the placeholder but are not part
  of the placeholder, such as “${noun}ification”.

2) Follow my twisted workaround

In a regular django template you can place {{ verbatium}} {{end verbatium}} around javascript, but you are using Python's new string Template.  I think you are going to have to sanitize your string in some manner, then reverse it after the substitution. You would have to first load your file as a string, then convert to a template

```
with open("/path/to/myfile.txt", "rb") as myfile:
   initial = "/n".join(myfile.readlines()[1:])
initial.replace('$(this)',"QXQQQXQ")
src = Template(initial)
result = src.substitute(d)
result.replace("QXQQQXQ", '$(this)')
```

3) Just use regular django Templates

Django templates have all sorts of constructs that lets you turn dictionary data into a functioning web page beyond simple value substitutions

Comment: Hi, I got the error "AttributeError: 'Template' object has no attribute 'replace'" on the line, "src.replace('$(this)', "QXQQQXQ")".